# I tried to update the data in table using this mongo query

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query

I read about updating the key inside of map in mongo, but missed saving the doc. could anyone tell me what this `false true` does full query below

`db.table.update({}, {$rename:{"user_id.attr":"user_id.attrs"}}, false, true)`

It is working fine,but I am unable to understand how false true is working

Comment: the query `update` only accept max `3 parameters`, and the 3rd parameter must be an `Object`. i dont think that query works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Official Documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). `false` and `true` refer to optional parameters `upsert` and `multi` respectively.

`upsert: false` means it does not insert a new document if no match is found.
`multi: true` means all the documents that match the `query` will be updated.